# @scope("request") is not working, spring mvc still returns a singleton

Tags: spring-mvc, web-applications, scope, request, singleton

I'm having issues with spring mvc returning a "Singleton" object, thereby exposing all the fields to multiple(simultaneous) web requests.
I tried to change the scope to "request", so i can get a new instance of the controller/service and dao objects, but i'm unable to get this to work as per HTTP request.

**Below are the code samples of my DAO, controller, service and domain objects**

```
@Component
@Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode    =ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class CountDaoImpl implements CountDao {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static Connection conn = null;

}

@Controller(value="countController")
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
@Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode =ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class CountController {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("CountServiceImpl")
CountService CountService; 
.
.
.
 }

@Service("CountServiceImpl")
@Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode     =ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class CountServiceImpl implements CountService {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("countDaoImpl")
private  CountDao  CountDao;
}

@Component
@Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode =ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class Count implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 9931247627087666L;
private Owners owners;
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

}

Below is my web.xml that has "RequestContextListener" just as mentioned in the [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
 <display-name>PortletApp</display-name>
 <session-config>
  <session-timeout>0</session-timeout>
 </session-config>
 <jsp-config>
  <taglib>
   <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0</taglib-uri>
   <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/liferay-portlet.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
  <taglib>
   <taglib-uri>http://liferay.com/tld/aui</taglib-uri>
   <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/aui.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>  
 </jsp-config>
 <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>view-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>view-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/servlet/view</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Below is the "Count-portlet.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        ">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.count" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>


    <bean id="viewResolver" 
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I would like a single object created per HTTP request for every class above.
Could someone tell me where i'm going wrong?

Comment: Define "not working". What is your code doing? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead?

Comment: Two separate HTTP requests are getting the same object and therefore the fields are visible to both requests. If both are simultaneous requests, Request2  often encounters closed connections/resultsets because Request 1 closed those after it was done with its work

Comment: I want a separate object to be created per http request, so two simultaneous request do not collide with each other. That was my intention behind switching to @scope("request")... but using {@Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode     =ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)} has made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's kind of late, but i hope this helps someone.

```
@Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode =ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
```

I'm guessing since all my classes were implementing interfaces i had use this proxy mode.

Comment: it did. Thanks a lot